# Some files are deleted after RPM upgrade

Tags: upgrade, rpm, rpm-spec

I have 2 RPM files. In RPM1 I have for example File.xml. In RPM2 this file is not present, but I create it via some scripts. As I know, after Upgrade, if the file is not in the list of RPM2 it will be deleted. Is there any configurations in the Spec file not to delete this file?

The easiest solution is to create a dummy file in the RPM2. But I would like to use SPEC file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if the file is not in the list of RPM2 it will be deleted

no. The list of files are the files that the rpm detains. If you remove the rpm, then those files will be removed. Custom files that you create in %post scripts for example will not be removed, because `rpm` doesn't know who they belong to.

Example part of a spec file:

```
%post
echo "content" > /etc/file.xml

%files
/etc/file2.xml
```

when you install the rpm created with above spec file; `/etc/file.xml` and `/etc/file2.xml` will be present on the system.

If you now remove that rpm, `/etc/file2.xml` will be removed (because in the `%files` section), but `/etc/file.xml` will remain because it does not belong to your rpm.

Comment: It seems that I did not described in details. I have installed the RPM1 and in %files it has for example /opt/bla/* . So I have the file /opt/bla/file1.xml after installation of the RPM1.

Then we decided to improve our installation process. And in RPM2 we have the same section %files /opt/bla/*. But now, the file1.xml is deleted and is added to that folder via script. So in %post we run the script which creates this file1.xml file in the /opt/bla/ folder.

Comment: The issue now is during the Upgrade. As the file1.xml does not exist in the RPM2 list, it is deleted after the Upgrade. 

So the question is - is there any way to mark this file during Upgrade or not in spec file?

Comment: no, that is not possible I think.
You can try by specifying `%ghost /opt/bla/file1.xml` in your %files section; warning `rpm` that that file belongs to you if it might appear, but I'm not sure that will prevent the deletion upon upgrade.

Comment: Yeah, I saw the ghost configuration, but the same not sure it will help. Will try a little bit later. Thanks.

Comment: Not including a file in your `%files` section and then adding it in `%post` is *not* an improvement to your installation process; it's a deficiency.

Comment: @SergheiSanduleac any updates of this? Is your problem solved? If so please accept the answer.